# $B$ is compact, convex, equilibrated, and has $0$ as an interior point then $B$ is the unit ball of a norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A set $B$ in a finite-dimensional real or complex vector space $V$ with
positive dimension where $B$ is compact, convex, equilibrated, and has $0$ as an interior point implies that $B$ is the unit ball of a norm, with the function defined by
$\|x\|=\min\{1/t: t>0\text{ and }tx \in B\}$ if $x$ is not zero, and $\|x\|=0$ if $x=0$.

Can someone help me show that $\|tx\|=|t|\,\|x\|$ for all $t$ in the complex number?

This problem is in the book “Matrix Analysis” 2nd edition by R. Horn and C. Johnson, page 337, Theorem 5.5.8.

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ is a complex number then $tcx \in B$ iff $t|c|x \in B$. Hence $\|cx\|=\inf \{\frac 1 t: t(cx)\in B\}=\inf \{\frac 1 t: t(|c|x)\in B\}=\inf \{\frac {|c|} t: tx\in B\} =|c|\|x\|$.

Comment: How did you show that tcx∈B  iff t|c|x∈B?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy I can show that tcx∈B iff t|c|x∈B if c is real by using the equilibrated property since |c| is just ±c but when c is complex i dont know anymore since we will have |c|=$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ whenever c=a+bi.

Comment: @Juandelacruz This is the first time I am seeing the word equlibrated. It is not standard English word. My guess is that in the complex case it means $cy\in B$ whenever $y \in B$ and $|c| \leq 1$. With this definition my proof works because $t|c|x=\frac {|c|} c (tcx)$.

Comment: A set is equilibrated iff $x\in B$ implies $\alpha x\in B$ for all scalars $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|=1$ (modulus of alpha is 1).  That is the definition of equilibrated in the reference book.

Comment: @Juandelacruz In that case my answer is correct because $|\frac {|c|} c|=1$.

Comment: Yes! you're right. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: 1 last question, is it okay to use min instead of inf? because in the book they have used min i think because the set B is compact and by the weierstrass theorem the min exists inside the set. am i right?

Comment: @Juandelacruz Yes, by compactness the minimum is attained at some $t$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! :)